# My phone numbers in my favorite list now shows no names?

Tags: ios, contacts

Under my "favorites" tab it now only shows phone numbers with no contacts name.

Comment: You mabe deactivated your iCloud contacts. Look at your "Contacts" app...its probably empty!

Answer (score 1):

Your account is probably inactive, either because you've turned it off or changed your password. Go to Settings → Mail, Contacts & Calendars and tap the account that you use to store your contacts. Make sure the Contacts service is on.